# How can I assign an image in mdpi folder to an ImageView in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, image, xamarin, layout

How can I assign an image to an ImageView in Xamarin?

To do this before what I did was to add the images to "drawable" and from design mode (Designing Layout) I select the image in the "src" field, leaving something like this:

> src | @ drawable / splashlogo

and if I wanted to do it from code at runtime I just put:

```
var drawableImage = Resources.GetDrawable (Resources.GetIdentifier ("splashlogo", "drawable", PackageName));
ProfileIcon.Background = (drawableImage);
```

The problem with this method is that I started having memory consumption problems because the resolution of the images was very high, and now that I am using the folders intended for each screen density (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi ...) I don't know how assign the images neither at runtime nor in the layout design.

Could someone tell me how to do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Cheesebaron said,Android will automatically pick the correct image based on the display density from your mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi folders.if you want to set Image of your mipmap in you code-behind,you could try this:

```
ProfileIcon.SetImageResource(Resource.Mipmap.splashlogo);
```

or

```
var drawableImage = Resources.GetDrawable(Resources.GetIdentifier("splashlogo", "mipmap", PackageName));
ProfileIcon.SetImageDrawable(drawableImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing should change. Android will automatically pick the correct image based on the display density.

Also when assigning image from code-behind instead of in layout. Consider just passing along the Resource Id to the ImageView, instead of first loading the drawable into memory, then pass it along to the ImageView. This can simply be done like:

```cs
ProfileIcon.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.splashlogo);
```

Otherwise, if you insist on loading it from resources first, I highly suggest you put it in a using statement to dispose of the managed side:

```cs
using(var drawableImage = Resources.GetDrawable(Resources.GetIdentifier ("splashlogo", "drawable", PackageName)))
    ProfileIcon.Background = (drawableImage);
```

Comment: I tried that: `ProfileIcon.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.splashlogo);` and didn't worked.
But also found the correct method for me, and is this: `ProfileIcon.SetImageResource(Resource.Mipmap.splashlogo);`
This way Android uses one of the mipmap folders (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, etc.)

Comment: This couldn't be derived from your description. You didn't mention you had put your images into the mipmap folders instead of drawables.

Comment: Well in my project the mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi folders are mipmap folders.
I have this:
´drawable
mipmap-hdpi
mipmap-mdpi
mipmap-xhdpi´

Check it out: [ https://ibb.co/K5SDWfy ]